# Unregistered people asking questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, new-users

I've noticed over the last month or so(?) that there's alot of people marked unknown with a rep of 1 asking low-quality questions that quickly get closed.

I remember when I started out with stack overflow you couldn't even ask a question until you had gained some rep by answering a few.

Why did that change? I think it helped raise the quality of questions by filtering out the people who are 'all give and no take'.

Comment: Did you join during the beta, or shortly thereafter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's changed - I think it's *always* been that way. The bar was always meant to be low for asking questions, with suitable encouragement to make them *good* questions.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I'm crazy :)

Comment: @Jon, How did you get the sockpuppet gravatar to show, when your profile has your normal picture?

Comment: @Lance - your browser has it cached; I see Jon... Tony is busy with prep for the play.

Comment: @Marc, thanks, time to clean that cache.