# Migrate to codereview as a voting option

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, migrated-questions, code-review-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Option to move post from Stackoverflow to codereview.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91877/option-to-move-post-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview-stackexchange)
>   [Suggest move to Code Review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123253/suggest-move-to-code-review)

We're getting a few questions in SO that would be better suited to codereview.  However, in the "off topic" vote option, there's no option for codereview as the site the question should be migrated to.

I think adding codereview as an option would be worthwhile, has there been any kind of discussion regarding adding it?  If so, what was the outcome?