# Why isn't "Stack overflow has too many too localized questions" migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

[Stack Overflow has too many "too localised" new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105365/stack-overflow-has-too-many-too-localised-new-questions) is closed as relating to only one site, but it is a highly voted question that seems to be of importance. I understand why it was closed, but why hasn't it been migrated?

Comment: Because it is 4 years old? What harm does it do here?

Comment: @Oded I was just figuring that a question with 90 votes and multiple helpful answers pertaining to stack overflow should be migrated, regardless of if it's closed or not.

Comment: It might get migrated, but given that MSE **was** MSO until fairly recently, there are lots of SO specific posts here. The prominent ones do get migrated, over time, but there are lots of them and no real process behind it.

Comment: There are literally tens of thousands of SO questions on MSE that need to be migrated back.  High priority ones are the first to go, and usually only when someone brings it to the mod's attention.  If you think it should go, flag it, select "other" and state your case.  If someone agrees, they may migrate it.  If not, then it stays for a bit longer.

Comment: @Won't No, you shouldn't just be flagging every single question from before the MSE/MSO split for migration.  You'll just get them all declined and piss off the mods.  It's not like all of the questions are intended to be migrated eventually.  The only questions that are even under consideration for migrating would be very high quality questions *still under active discussion*, and even then, this far from the split, in most situations it would be correct to just post a new question on MSO if you have a new point to raise on the topic.

Comment: I'll flag ones with a lot of votes to bring them into consideration as soon as the staff team sees it possible.

Comment: @Servy Nowhere did I say to flag all of them.  That's ridiculous.  Now, if someone did try to do that, not only would they be wasting their time, it'd be hilarious when they got their account suspended.

Comment: @Wyatt No, you should not be going around flagging old question just because they have lots of votes.  The only questions even under consideration for migration are those *under active discussion*.

Comment: @Won't You said that all of them should be migrated eventually, which is entirely false.  The intention is that almost all of the remaining questions from before the migration just won't be migrated.  The "high priority" items for migration that you mentioned are *the things that have already been migrated*.

Comment: @Servy Please don't read things into my comment that aren't even there.  Except for this -->         <-- I absolutely meant that.

Comment: @Won't This: `There are literally tens of thousands of SO questions on MSE that need to be migrated back.` isn't exactly ambiguous.  It's not like I'm reading between the lines there.  You then follow it up with the advice of, "just flag it and let the mods sort it out" rather than providing any actual guidelines on what types of questions should be flagged.

Comment: @Servy Yet you leave out the interstitial lines about high priority and how they usually only get migrated `when someone brings it to the mod's attention`, as well as the suggestion that a flag should be placed if the user `think[s] it should go`.  I get it--you don't think I was clear enough in my **comment** (ironic bolding is ironic).  Fine.  I don't think agree.

Comment: @Won't That's because all of those points are *based on a false premise*.  You start with the premise that all of the posts should be migrated eventually.  **That's not true**.  The intention is to just not migrate this content *ever*.  Stating that they're only considered for migration when someone flags for mod attention is *encouraging him to incorrectly flag*.  Saying you think he should flag it if he thinks it should go *when policy says they shouldn't go*, resulting in his flags just being declined, is not helpful.  I don't think your comment was  unclear, I think it was *wrong*.